# Sort/filter txt file in excel

Tags: excel, vba, import

I would appreciate help:

I have txt file which I need to import to excel, format it and filter out some data:
TXT file to import:

| # ASCII printout of data |  |
| --- | --- |
| # |  |
| # |  |
| # P01R13 |  |
|  | 1 15.930000 |
|  | 2 15.880000 |
|  | 3 15.920000 |
|  | 4 15.880000 |
|  | 5 15.850000 |
|  | 6 17.500000 |
|  | 7 15.810000 |
|  | 8 15.770000 |
|  | 9 15.770000 |
|  | 10 15.740000 |
|  | 11 15.730000 |
|  | 12 15.750000 |
| # |  |
| # P01R14 |  |
|  | 1 15.930000 |
|  | 2 17.500000 |
|  | 3 15.920000 |
|  | 4 15.880000 |
|  | 5 15.850000 |
|  | 6 17.500000 |
|  | 7 15.810000 |
|  | 8 15.770000 |
|  | 9 15.770000 |
|  | 10 15.740000 |
|  | 11 15.730000 |
|  | 12 15.750000 |
| # |  |
| # P01R15 |  |
|  | 1 15.930000 |
|  | 2 15.880000 |
|  | 3 15.920000 |
|  | 4 15.880000 |
|  | 5 15.850000 |
|  | 6 15.850000 |
|  | 7 15.810000 |
|  | 8 15.770000 |
|  | 9 15.770000 |
|  | 10 17.500000 |
|  | 11 15.730000 |
|  | 12 15.750000 |

[Same data as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPyXj.png)

I need to get the list of every sensor, which value jumps by more than 1.0.

For instance, there are 3 sensors: P01R13, P01R14, P01R15. So final result will be the list of all of three sensors as all of them have jump by more than 1.0: Sensor P01R13 changes value by more than 1.0 at measurement No.6, Sensor P01R14 changes value by more than 1.0 at measurement No.2, Sensor P01R15 changes value by more than 1.0 at measurement No.10.

Number of measurement can start from 1000 or any other number. The idea is to compare each measurement with previous and next and if the change is more than 1m then take the name of the sensor to the list.

I expect the list looking like this.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong? Both a formula based approach and a VBA approach are feasable here.

Comment: Power Query can handle this easily. Please edit your question to show what you have tried and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

For a straight and simple formula based solution, paste this in a new sheet:

| # ASCII printout of data |  | Sensor tag | Sensor measurement index | Value | Index for delta > 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # |  | `=IF(A2="",OFFSET(C2,-1,0),A2)` | `=IF(B2="","",LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B2="","",MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E2<>"",E1<>""),IF(ABS(E2-E1)>1,D2,""),"")` |
| # |  | `=IF(A3="",OFFSET(C3,-1,0),A3)` | `=IF(B3="","",LEFT(B3,FIND(" ",B3)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B3="","",MID(B3,FIND(" ",B3),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E3<>"",E2<>""),IF(ABS(E3-E2)>1,D3,""),"")` |
| # P01R13 |  | `=IF(A4="",OFFSET(C4,-1,0),A4)` | `=IF(B4="","",LEFT(B4,FIND(" ",B4)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B4="","",MID(B4,FIND(" ",B4),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E4<>"",E3<>""),IF(ABS(E4-E3)>1,D4,""),"")` |
|  | 1 15,930000 | `=IF(A5="",OFFSET(C5,-1,0),A5)` | `=IF(B5="","",LEFT(B5,FIND(" ",B5)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B5="","",MID(B5,FIND(" ",B5),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E5<>"",E4<>""),IF(ABS(E5-E4)>1,D5,""),"")` |
|  | 2 15,880000 | `=IF(A6="",OFFSET(C6,-1,0),A6)` | `=IF(B6="","",LEFT(B6,FIND(" ",B6)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B6="","",MID(B6,FIND(" ",B6),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E6<>"",E5<>""),IF(ABS(E6-E5)>1,D6,""),"")` |
|  | 3 15,920000 | `=IF(A7="",OFFSET(C7,-1,0),A7)` | `=IF(B7="","",LEFT(B7,FIND(" ",B7)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B7="","",MID(B7,FIND(" ",B7),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E7<>"",E6<>""),IF(ABS(E7-E6)>1,D7,""),"")` |
|  | 4 15,880000 | `=IF(A8="",OFFSET(C8,-1,0),A8)` | `=IF(B8="","",LEFT(B8,FIND(" ",B8)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B8="","",MID(B8,FIND(" ",B8),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E8<>"",E7<>""),IF(ABS(E8-E7)>1,D8,""),"")` |
|  | 5 15,850000 | `=IF(A9="",OFFSET(C9,-1,0),A9)` | `=IF(B9="","",LEFT(B9,FIND(" ",B9)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B9="","",MID(B9,FIND(" ",B9),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E9<>"",E8<>""),IF(ABS(E9-E8)>1,D9,""),"")` |
|  | 6 17,500000 | `=IF(A10="",OFFSET(C10,-1,0),A10)` | `=IF(B10="","",LEFT(B10,FIND(" ",B10)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B10="","",MID(B10,FIND(" ",B10),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E10<>"",E9<>""),IF(ABS(E10-E9)>1,D10,""),"")` |
|  | 7 15,810000 | `=IF(A11="",OFFSET(C11,-1,0),A11)` | `=IF(B11="","",LEFT(B11,FIND(" ",B11)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B11="","",MID(B11,FIND(" ",B11),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E11<>"",E10<>""),IF(ABS(E11-E10)>1,D11,""),"")` |
|  | 8 15,770000 | `=IF(A12="",OFFSET(C12,-1,0),A12)` | `=IF(B12="","",LEFT(B12,FIND(" ",B12)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B12="","",MID(B12,FIND(" ",B12),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E12<>"",E11<>""),IF(ABS(E12-E11)>1,D12,""),"")` |
|  | 9 15,770000 | `=IF(A13="",OFFSET(C13,-1,0),A13)` | `=IF(B13="","",LEFT(B13,FIND(" ",B13)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B13="","",MID(B13,FIND(" ",B13),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E13<>"",E12<>""),IF(ABS(E13-E12)>1,D13,""),"")` |
|  | 10 15,740000 | `=IF(A14="",OFFSET(C14,-1,0),A14)` | `=IF(B14="","",LEFT(B14,FIND(" ",B14)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B14="","",MID(B14,FIND(" ",B14),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E14<>"",E13<>""),IF(ABS(E14-E13)>1,D14,""),"")` |
|  | 11 15,730000 | `=IF(A15="",OFFSET(C15,-1,0),A15)` | `=IF(B15="","",LEFT(B15,FIND(" ",B15)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B15="","",MID(B15,FIND(" ",B15),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E15<>"",E14<>""),IF(ABS(E15-E14)>1,D15,""),"")` |
|  | 12 15,750000 | `=IF(A16="",OFFSET(C16,-1,0),A16)` | `=IF(B16="","",LEFT(B16,FIND(" ",B16)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B16="","",MID(B16,FIND(" ",B16),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E16<>"",E15<>""),IF(ABS(E16-E15)>1,D16,""),"")` |
| # |  | `=IF(A17="",OFFSET(C17,-1,0),A17)` | `=IF(B17="","",LEFT(B17,FIND(" ",B17)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B17="","",MID(B17,FIND(" ",B17),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E17<>"",E16<>""),IF(ABS(E17-E16)>1,D17,""),"")` |
| # P01R14 |  | `=IF(A18="",OFFSET(C18,-1,0),A18)` | `=IF(B18="","",LEFT(B18,FIND(" ",B18)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B18="","",MID(B18,FIND(" ",B18),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E18<>"",E17<>""),IF(ABS(E18-E17)>1,D18,""),"")` |
|  | 1 15,930000 | `=IF(A19="",OFFSET(C19,-1,0),A19)` | `=IF(B19="","",LEFT(B19,FIND(" ",B19)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B19="","",MID(B19,FIND(" ",B19),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E19<>"",E18<>""),IF(ABS(E19-E18)>1,D19,""),"")` |
|  | 2 17,500000 | `=IF(A20="",OFFSET(C20,-1,0),A20)` | `=IF(B20="","",LEFT(B20,FIND(" ",B20)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B20="","",MID(B20,FIND(" ",B20),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E20<>"",E19<>""),IF(ABS(E20-E19)>1,D20,""),"")` |
|  | 3 15,920000 | `=IF(A21="",OFFSET(C21,-1,0),A21)` | `=IF(B21="","",LEFT(B21,FIND(" ",B21)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B21="","",MID(B21,FIND(" ",B21),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E21<>"",E20<>""),IF(ABS(E21-E20)>1,D21,""),"")` |
|  | 4 15,880000 | `=IF(A22="",OFFSET(C22,-1,0),A22)` | `=IF(B22="","",LEFT(B22,FIND(" ",B22)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B22="","",MID(B22,FIND(" ",B22),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E22<>"",E21<>""),IF(ABS(E22-E21)>1,D22,""),"")` |
|  | 5 15,850000 | `=IF(A23="",OFFSET(C23,-1,0),A23)` | `=IF(B23="","",LEFT(B23,FIND(" ",B23)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B23="","",MID(B23,FIND(" ",B23),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E23<>"",E22<>""),IF(ABS(E23-E22)>1,D23,""),"")` |
|  | 6 17,500000 | `=IF(A24="",OFFSET(C24,-1,0),A24)` | `=IF(B24="","",LEFT(B24,FIND(" ",B24)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B24="","",MID(B24,FIND(" ",B24),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E24<>"",E23<>""),IF(ABS(E24-E23)>1,D24,""),"")` |
|  | 7 15,810000 | `=IF(A25="",OFFSET(C25,-1,0),A25)` | `=IF(B25="","",LEFT(B25,FIND(" ",B25)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B25="","",MID(B25,FIND(" ",B25),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E25<>"",E24<>""),IF(ABS(E25-E24)>1,D25,""),"")` |
|  | 8 15,770000 | `=IF(A26="",OFFSET(C26,-1,0),A26)` | `=IF(B26="","",LEFT(B26,FIND(" ",B26)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B26="","",MID(B26,FIND(" ",B26),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E26<>"",E25<>""),IF(ABS(E26-E25)>1,D26,""),"")` |
|  | 9 15,770000 | `=IF(A27="",OFFSET(C27,-1,0),A27)` | `=IF(B27="","",LEFT(B27,FIND(" ",B27)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B27="","",MID(B27,FIND(" ",B27),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E27<>"",E26<>""),IF(ABS(E27-E26)>1,D27,""),"")` |
|  | 10 15,740000 | `=IF(A28="",OFFSET(C28,-1,0),A28)` | `=IF(B28="","",LEFT(B28,FIND(" ",B28)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B28="","",MID(B28,FIND(" ",B28),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E28<>"",E27<>""),IF(ABS(E28-E27)>1,D28,""),"")` |
|  | 11 15,730000 | `=IF(A29="",OFFSET(C29,-1,0),A29)` | `=IF(B29="","",LEFT(B29,FIND(" ",B29)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B29="","",MID(B29,FIND(" ",B29),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E29<>"",E28<>""),IF(ABS(E29-E28)>1,D29,""),"")` |
|  | 12 15,750000 | `=IF(A30="",OFFSET(C30,-1,0),A30)` | `=IF(B30="","",LEFT(B30,FIND(" ",B30)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B30="","",MID(B30,FIND(" ",B30),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E30<>"",E29<>""),IF(ABS(E30-E29)>1,D30,""),"")` |
| # |  | `=IF(A31="",OFFSET(C31,-1,0),A31)` | `=IF(B31="","",LEFT(B31,FIND(" ",B31)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B31="","",MID(B31,FIND(" ",B31),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E31<>"",E30<>""),IF(ABS(E31-E30)>1,D31,""),"")` |
| # P01R15 |  | `=IF(A32="",OFFSET(C32,-1,0),A32)` | `=IF(B32="","",LEFT(B32,FIND(" ",B32)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B32="","",MID(B32,FIND(" ",B32),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E32<>"",E31<>""),IF(ABS(E32-E31)>1,D32,""),"")` |
|  | 1 15,930000 | `=IF(A33="",OFFSET(C33,-1,0),A33)` | `=IF(B33="","",LEFT(B33,FIND(" ",B33)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B33="","",MID(B33,FIND(" ",B33),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E33<>"",E32<>""),IF(ABS(E33-E32)>1,D33,""),"")` |
|  | 2 15,880000 | `=IF(A34="",OFFSET(C34,-1,0),A34)` | `=IF(B34="","",LEFT(B34,FIND(" ",B34)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B34="","",MID(B34,FIND(" ",B34),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E34<>"",E33<>""),IF(ABS(E34-E33)>1,D34,""),"")` |
|  | 3 15,920000 | `=IF(A35="",OFFSET(C35,-1,0),A35)` | `=IF(B35="","",LEFT(B35,FIND(" ",B35)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B35="","",MID(B35,FIND(" ",B35),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E35<>"",E34<>""),IF(ABS(E35-E34)>1,D35,""),"")` |
|  | 4 15,880000 | `=IF(A36="",OFFSET(C36,-1,0),A36)` | `=IF(B36="","",LEFT(B36,FIND(" ",B36)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B36="","",MID(B36,FIND(" ",B36),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E36<>"",E35<>""),IF(ABS(E36-E35)>1,D36,""),"")` |
|  | 5 15,850000 | `=IF(A37="",OFFSET(C37,-1,0),A37)` | `=IF(B37="","",LEFT(B37,FIND(" ",B37)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B37="","",MID(B37,FIND(" ",B37),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E37<>"",E36<>""),IF(ABS(E37-E36)>1,D37,""),"")` |
|  | 6 15,850000 | `=IF(A38="",OFFSET(C38,-1,0),A38)` | `=IF(B38="","",LEFT(B38,FIND(" ",B38)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B38="","",MID(B38,FIND(" ",B38),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E38<>"",E37<>""),IF(ABS(E38-E37)>1,D38,""),"")` |
|  | 7 15,810000 | `=IF(A39="",OFFSET(C39,-1,0),A39)` | `=IF(B39="","",LEFT(B39,FIND(" ",B39)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B39="","",MID(B39,FIND(" ",B39),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E39<>"",E38<>""),IF(ABS(E39-E38)>1,D39,""),"")` |
|  | 8 15,770000 | `=IF(A40="",OFFSET(C40,-1,0),A40)` | `=IF(B40="","",LEFT(B40,FIND(" ",B40)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B40="","",MID(B40,FIND(" ",B40),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E40<>"",E39<>""),IF(ABS(E40-E39)>1,D40,""),"")` |
|  | 9 15,770000 | `=IF(A41="",OFFSET(C41,-1,0),A41)` | `=IF(B41="","",LEFT(B41,FIND(" ",B41)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B41="","",MID(B41,FIND(" ",B41),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E41<>"",E40<>""),IF(ABS(E41-E40)>1,D41,""),"")` |
|  | 10 17,500000 | `=IF(A42="",OFFSET(C42,-1,0),A42)` | `=IF(B42="","",LEFT(B42,FIND(" ",B42)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B42="","",MID(B42,FIND(" ",B42),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E42<>"",E41<>""),IF(ABS(E42-E41)>1,D42,""),"")` |
|  | 11 15,730000 | `=IF(A43="",OFFSET(C43,-1,0),A43)` | `=IF(B43="","",LEFT(B43,FIND(" ",B43)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B43="","",MID(B43,FIND(" ",B43),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E43<>"",E42<>""),IF(ABS(E43-E42)>1,D43,""),"")` |
|  | 12 15,750000 | `=IF(A44="",OFFSET(C44,-1,0),A44)` | `=IF(B44="","",LEFT(B44,FIND(" ",B44)-1)*1)` | `=IF(B44="","",MID(B44,FIND(" ",B44),999)*1)` | `=IF(AND(E44<>"",E43<>""),IF(ABS(E44-E43)>1,D44,""),"")` |

You can then use a pivot table sourcing from columns C:F; use "Sensor tag" (column C) for rows and min value of "Index for delta > 1" (column F) for values; remove empty cells and # from the rows' values of the pivot table. The final result should be something like this:

[image: Final result as picture]